# Y-axis scale uneven

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

When using Chart.js i cant find a way to evenly scale the Y axis. Overiding and using manual scaling( scaleOverride: true ) for every chart is not really an option since there are alot of them and they have different data. Some one have an idea how to fix the scaling of the data?

This is the scaling i want:
[image: This is the scaling i want]

Sometimes the scaling gets uneven depending on the data.

[image]

Comment: The "X-axis" is the horizontal, left-right axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the options globally - this will apply to every chart instance. For instance

```
Chart.defaults.global.scaleOverride = true;
...
```

Comment: If i have global scaleoveride and step and stepwidth on charts with different data, how do you think that would look?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand your question. that would depend on your data, no? By the way, you could always pick from a predefined set of option objects depending on the range of your data.

Comment: i ended up defining the max value for the scale per table adding it as a parameter to the view objects and splitting that by five to get the steps .. :)
Thanks for input!

Comment: No worries! When you get the time, you might want to add your solution as an answer and accept it. I think this is a common enough problem. Cheers!